# Check-out and open a Jupyter notebook from Perforce Helix Visual Client

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, perforce, anaconda3

I am using the Perforce Helix Visual Client (P4V)  for version control. I need to check-out/edit a jupyter notebook under a particular Anaconda environment.

I don't know how to use a particular jupyter notebooks version as the default application to open .ipynb files from within P4V.

Application Versions:

- Helix Visual Client Rev. P4V/NTX64/2019.2/1883366.
- Anaconda3 version 2.1.1
- Jupyter Notebook 6.4.6

The path to the .ipynb file in the local Perforce workspace is:

```
c:\Users\user\Perforce\myworkspace_6673\mynotebook_Rev.1.0.00.ipynb
```

Relevant Anaconda3 paths:

```
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\cwp.py 
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe 
C:\Users\rodrigd3\Anaconda3\Scripts
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py
```

Comment: What's the problem?  It sounds like the file is already in your workspace, so what happens when you right-click it and "Check Out"?

Comment: I can check out the .ipynb file within the workspace by right clicking and "Check Out". Next, I want to use  "Open Wit" directly from the Perforce client.  However, I don't know what executable to select among several found under _Anaconda3\Scripts_ to open the notebook under a specific Anaconda Navigator environment other than the _base(root)_ environment.

Comment: That sounds like a question about Anaconda(?) rather than Perforce.  Have you tried just going through the different executables one by one to see which one works as you expect?

Comment: Correct, it is more generally about Anaconda. Within the scripts directory of the environment I see 59 executables. I've tried several including the most obvious _jupyter-notebook.exe_ but not browser session is opened.

Comment: I can open the file via Anaconda Powershell by changing the directory to my the Peroforce workspace directory, running _jupyter notebook_, and selecting the target .ipynb file. However this manual process can result in editing the incorrect notebook within a different workspace. It would be best if an executable could be defined as teh default means of opening the file for editing. Perhaps choosing an IDE other than **Jupyter notebooks** may work better. Perhaps **PyCharm**?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've added additional detail to the description of what I need to accomplish within P4V.